# Removing Some Content from website by giving 410 status code

Tags: seo, htaccess, php, 404, 410-gone

I have some content to be permanently deleted from my website. This is a permanent deletion and I am planning to give 410 status code.

I can very well return the status code in PHP page as

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone" );
exit
```

or using rewrite rule in .htacccess as

```
RewriteRule ^deleted/ - [L,R=410]
```

I am clear till this point. However, I would like to redirect users to another page to explain why some pages are no more available.

So, is a redirect to another page with 410 code fine? I am specifically asking this, because I feel it is confusing to redirect to such a page (where search engine may take it as a redirect), but then giving 410 code at the same time.

What is the right approach for this. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is a redirect to another page with 410 code fine?

A redirect is not necessary. Define a custom 410 error document:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /error-docs/e410.php
```

And trigger the 410 in `.htaccess`, as you did before:

```
RewriteRule ^deleted/ - [G]
```

The `G` flag is simply a shortcut for `R=410` and the `L` flag is not required (it is implied when using a status code other than 3xx).

The error document `/error-docs/e410.php` is called using an internal subrequest (no external redirect).

In `e410.php` you can examine the URL that triggered the 410 (ie. `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`) if you wish to deliver a specific message for different URLs.

> I am specifically asking this, because I feel it is confusing to redirect to such a page (where search engine may take it as a redirect), but then giving 410 code at the same time.

Yes, it is confusing and inefficient. Although search engines will ultimately see the 410 Gone status - so it should still "work" indirectly. But this is inefficient (2 requests/responses) - a 3xx followed by a 410 (in the 2nd - redirected - response). If you "redirect" to your error document then you can't examine details of the initial request that triggered the 410 in the first place.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: this is very clear answer and things look simpler now. I was totally confused and you saved my day. thanks